# Google Calendar API Library (PHP) - Where is the documentation?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have been looking for documentation of the Google Calendar API functions, methods, etc. from the PHP Google Client Library, but can't for the life of me find the damn thing.  Does anyone know where this lives?  I went in the Groups, but there is a 2 month old question for the same thing:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-api-php-client/pP-E1noaqsI

Any ideas here?

Comment: Why the hell is this closed as Off Topic?
Google API's support page links to StackOverflow, so one is supposed to ask questions about it in StackOverflow. This is a perfectly legitimate question, and it IS related to programming.
And the legitimate answer here seems to be that such a documentation does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Overview:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

PHP Sample Downloads:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples#Calendar_API

Methods:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately, though, this does not answer my question.  All of that documentation is for the REST API, I was looking for support documentation to the client library.  Any idea where that may be?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the reference guide for the REST API:
   https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Each API method has a PHP code sample. For example, if you wanted to update the `CalendarList` you would visit:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/update

Comment: If it is anything like the DRIVE documentation, then it likely does not show you very much. We would love to see google spend a bit of time creating actual documentation on their PHP library similar to how jQuery spends time working through ALL of the methods available in the library. Very little is said about how to use the client library. The library itself is a 64 file jumble with no real documentation about what to include and when.

Comment: Yup been spending hours trying to figure out how to use the client library. I got the calendar list to spit out but what do I do with that. Its not showing anything from my calendar after giving authorization... The documentation is worthless. I am just searching around for some actual examples. If I ever figure this out I will write a detailed documentation. All I want to do is show a user their calendar when they are logged into a website...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Zend GData Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html)?